# without subscription in microsoft azure is it possible to get access token for office 365?-swift

Tags: ios, swift, office365api

I am making an ios app which integrate onedrive api and its giving me this error while signing in to office 365 and (i didn't subscribe in microsoft azure is it the problem?)

> systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is
>   /Users/OdysseyApps/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/19CE4531-2058-46DD-8F7C-DB3B6ACC06DC/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>   2017-03-14 17:23:46.379838 onedrive[861:28260] [MC] Reading from
>   private effective user settings. 2017-03-14 17:24:06.853
>   onedrive[861:28260] -[ADAuthenticationBroker
>   webAuthenticationDidCancel][353][main] 2017-03-14 17:24:06.872
>   onedrive[861:28260] ADALiOS [2017-03-14 11:24:06 -
>   C0176528-6FB0-4085-BD79-F59FB164A673] ERROR: Error raised: 1.
>   Additional Information: Domain: ADAuthenticationErrorDomain
>   ProtocolCode:(null) Details:The user has cancelled the authorization..
>   ErrorCode: 1. 2017-03-14 17:24:07.398 onedrive[861:28260] ADALiOS
>   [2017-03-14 11:24:07 - C0176528-6FB0-4085-BD79-F59FB164A673] ERROR:
>   Error raised: 1. Additional Information: Domain:
>   ADAuthenticationErrorDomain ProtocolCode:(null) Details:The user has
>   cancelled the authorization.. ErrorCode: 1.

Is it possible to get access token of office 365 without subscribe in microsoft azure. or without access token is it possible to access one drive using one drive api

Comment: **The user has cancelled the authorization..** this line has come because i clicked on cancel button. when i sign in **sorry but we are having trouble signing you in** this page comes out and then i click the cancel button the above error appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible. At last I uploaded a file in one drive without Subscribe in mIcrosoft Azure. Here is the link https://github.com/microsoftgraph/ios-swift-snippets-sample